# Knexjs giving authentication error when running latest migrations for Nodejs project with SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, backend, knex.js

**SOLVED:-**
*For the solution, please refer to my comment in the comment section.*

I have recently started learning `knexjs` (I'm new to Databases) for connecting a Microsoft SQL Server with a Node.js backend. I am following [this YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfrn21E2NaU), and have created the following Node.js project structure -

```
|- knexjs (main folder)
   |- db
      |- migrations
         |- 20230307141431_init.js
      |- db.js
      |- knexfile.js
   |- node_modules
   |- index.js
   |- package-lock.json
   |- package.json
```

However, I am getting the below error at around `18:30` in the video, when migrating the latest changes in `20230307141431_init.js` to the database `knexjs_database` already created in the SQL Server. **I have rechecked the password and can confirm it is correct**.

Can anyone please help me with identifying the issue?

[image: Knexjs migration Error]

The command being executed for migration -
`npx knex migrate:latest --knexfile ./db/knexfile.js`

I have created a new user called `admin` and have added it to the Security group for `knexjs_database` (screenshot below).

[image: SSMS SQL Server]

**index.js**

```
    const express = require("express");
    
    const app = express();
    app.use(express.json());
    
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.end("Hello World!");
    });
    
    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
    });
```

**knexfile.js**

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: "mssql",
    connection: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 1433,
      database: "knexjs_database",
      user: "admin",
      password: "*********",
      options: {
        trustedConnection: true,
      },
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: "knex_migrations",
    },
  },
};
```

**db.js**

```
const knex = require("knex");
const knexfile = require("./knexfile");

const db = knex(knexfile.development);
module.exports = db;
```

**20230307141431_init.js**

```
exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable("person", (table) => {
    table.increments("id").primary();
    table.string("email").notNullable().unique();
    table.string("first_name").notNullable();
    table.string("last_name").notNullable();
    table.timestamps(true, true);
  });
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable("person");
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "knexjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "knex": "^2.4.2",
    "mssql": "^9.1.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If you're getting an login error, have you checked the SQL Server logs to get the true authentication error? If not, you should. If you have, what was it and what about the error don't you understand so we can try to elaborate.

Comment: Hi Larnu, thank you so much! I found out from the Server Logs that I provided the wrong password in `knexfile.js` (silly me!). However, even after providing the correct password, I was getting a `CREATE TABLE permission denied in database knexjs_database` error. Then after a little help from the internet, I selected the `db_owner` option for the user `admin`. After that, voila! It started working.

Thanks to you, I found out about the `SQL Server Logs` feature - it would for sure come in handy while debugging database issues in the future.